# how to diff dos format file

Tags: unix, diff, dos

how to diff dos format file with unix format file but they are  having content using diff command .  but most of time contant are same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [dos2unix](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_dos2uni.htm) command in unix to convert the dos file to unix an then compare.

Comment: what if I do not have the write access ? `dos2unix` tries to write a temp file during the conversion.

Answer (score 4):

`diff -b` ignores changes in spacing — including presence or absence of `\r` before `\n`.